# Whence comes increasing usage of "do" for "have" in ordering food?

Tags: contemporary-english, do

I have lately noticed, at both ends of a recent thousand-mile relocation within the USA, that people are increasingly using the verb “do” in ordering food, in place of that “have” which [various](https://learn-english.wonderhowto.com/how-to/use-verb-have-for-eating-and-drinking-298936/) [sites](https://www.englishpage.com/vocabulary/interactivelesson4a.htm) still model or enjoin for English language learners—as in (to a waiter) “I’ll *do* a Cobb salad.” Whence comes this trend, how widespread is it, and when did it arise?

Comment: Well, since everyone seems to also do lunch, dinner, breakfast and drinks, it is not a stretch to imagine they are "doing the food", as well. It's almost as bad (but not quite) as: "Can I **git** a tuna on rye?"

Comment: It's potentially confusing, as 'do' is also used for 'sell / provide / make [food]'. "Do you do a madras?"

Comment: I haven't heard that, I don't think.  I mean, I would understand it, but I'm not sure that I've heard that.  Now maybe I will.  Sometimes things fly by us until someone points them out.  Anyway, I agree with @Lambie .  People use "do" in "Let's do lunch," so it's not a stretch for someone to use "do," though technically, since "do" means "make," it kind of sounds like the person isn't ordering it but making it.  Maybe it means "I'll do/make my order..."  Or maybe we're overthinking it.  Anywho, I hope you find out where it came from.   

Comment: I agree with @EdwinAshworth , too.  I think I said as much, but it could possibly be confusing  to some people.

Comment: Just as a side not, in Italy, a country renowned  for food,  “fare” (to do) is commonly used to for ordering food. *“Mi faccio una pizza”*

Comment: You have fare la dolce far niente, and (for a long time) faire la plage, faire la piscine, etc in French.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - yes, though the correct form is “fare ***il*** dolce far niente.”

Comment: Yes, I remembered after the time for editing had expired.

Comment: “Whence comes”? More consistent would be “whence cometh?”, but contemporary usage is as I have edited your title.

Comment: I imagine it comes from the barbarian hordes who invaded Rome.

Comment: @David, neither TheFreeDictionary (a dictionary aggregator) nor Merriam-Webster tags *whence* as obsolete. Nor does the OED, though it says "Now replaced in ordinary colloquial speech by *where…from."* (I, of course, was using it *in writing.)* And I do not think you effected any real improvement over my escape-coded quotation marks--you even turned at least one backwards. I have accordingly opted to roll back your changes all together.

Comment: As thou wilt, sire.

Comment: Note that _do_ is a pro-verb, suitable for any active predicate. Pratchett's Death says things like "I COULD MURDER A CURRY", and anyone can do a curry or a pizza before the party.

Answer (score 8):

It appears to be an old usage, especially in BrE and AusE.

***[To do](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/tcccuoy)*** - to offer or consume:

> (a) to eat or drink, usu. with the relevant food or drink attached, e.g. *do a couple of pints, do a burger.*
>
> - 1849    [UK]    Sam Sly 31 Mar. 2/2: Ned, *the bricklayer, not to do his seven pints before breakfast.*
> - 1861    [Aus]   Bell’s Life in Sydney 18 May 3/3: *[He] betook himself to Bottomley's Temple of Bacchus [...] There he ‘did’ Bass No 3, October brewing in triplicate.*
> - 1972    [US]    Eble Campus Sl. Oct. 2: *do – general, all-purpose action verb: Let’s do a few beers.*

(GDoS)

Comment: Do a few beers, sure. But not when ordering food.

Comment: @Lambie - as you said in a comment, the move from “let’s do lunch” to “let’s do a salad” is an easy one.

Comment: Yes, I agree you say that to the person with you, but to the waiter?

Comment: Well, evidence provided by the OP appears to go in that direction.